# Internal Page Navigation with custom urls

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am looking for internal page navigation with custom urls. 
   Please refer my code.

Current Code :

```
<ul class="mdl-menu">
        <li class="mdl-menu__item"><a href="#" class="navText nav_link">Home</a></li>
        <li class="mdl-menu__item"><a href="#About" class="navText nav_link">About</a></li>
        <li class="mdl-menu__item"><a href="#LightUp" class="navText nav_link">Light Up</a></li>
        <li class="mdl-menu__item"><a href="#Events" class="navText nav_link">Events</a></li>
        <li class="mdl-menu__item"><a href="#SignUp" class="navText nav_link">Sign up</a></li>
        <li class="mdl-menu__item"><a href="#NCFMix" class="navText nav_link">NCF Mix</a></li>
        <li class="mdl-menu__item"><a href="#LightUpNCF" class="navText nav_link">#LightUpNCF</a></li>
      </ul>
```

Current OutPut : 
      main url : **"www.example.com/php/home.php"**

When I click on second menu button means **"About"**. it Navigates to targeted block with following URL.
     "www.example.com/php/home.php#About"

What I Expecting is 
     **"www.example.com/About"** or **"www.example.com/#About"**

I also tried `window.history.pushState('', '','/About');` 
This changes URL as I wanted, but when i refresh the same page it shows 404 error.
Please help me with this. Is there any way to implement this using JavaScript or PhP.

Thank in advanced.

Comment: URLs are like directory paths. You can make them appear differently with Javascript, but as soon as you actually use them, you get a 404 error because it's trying to browse to the directory **About** and search for an index file. The only (and best) option I know of to solve this problem, would be **mod_rewrite** with a .htaccess file. You can find an in-depth tutorial on how to use this here: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/an-in-depth-guide-to-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708

Answer (score 0):

If this is a home directory then create a .htaccess file and write this

```
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex home.php       
order deny,allow
```

You can also add the following rule

```
RewriteRule ^ home.php [QSA,L]
```

Comment: `Options -Indexes` - prevents listing of files `DirectoryIndex home.php` - Sets home.php as the index file. `order deny,allow` - Does nothing in this case. Conclusion: This solution is completely pointless and doesn't answer the question at all. `RewriteRule ^ home.php [QSA,L]` - Basicly rewrites everything to simple *home.php*, which isn't the question at all. It also requires mod_rewrite enabled inside Apache. Conclusion: Right direction, but not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

This Will help you please check:

Hashbangs (#!), hashes (#) and even the HTML5 History API (pushState, popState) all have issues. This article will go through the issues with each one, their use cases, then provide the evolution of their solutions. At the end with little bit of educated simplicity you'll be able to achieve better results; in terms of a better experience for your users as well as better compatibility, accessibility and maintainability in your solutions.

[Reference Link](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/wiki/Intelligent-State-Handling)